# how to extract image with multiple coordinates using opencv

Tags: opencv

I've 4 coordinates:
x1,y1
x2,y2
x3,y3
x4,y4

I'm unable to use opencv to extract image from multiple coordinates.
How to get it to work? How can I extract only the masked region?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


contours= 4, 429, 0, 386, 67, 368, 78, 411
file_path = "img_10.jpg"
# read image
img = cv2.imread(file_path, 1)
arr = np.array(contours).reshape(4, 2)
arr_points = np.array(arr, dtype=np.int32)
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, arr_points, 1)
mask = mask.astype(np.bool)
out = np.zeros_like(img)
out[mask] = img[mask]
cv2.imwrite('output.png', out)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, can you elaborate? That code doesn't really make sense (also is not a [mcve]), as you're trying to write a list of coordinates as if it was an image... | You mean something like find the [bounding rectangle](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366) and get ROI defined by this rectangle and save the ROI to PNG file?

Comment: @DanMašek Thank You, Dan for responding. I simply want to send in coordinates of points and extract an image using opencv. Like the points above. I'm not sure if i need to use convexHull. Please let me know how I can extract an image based on the points provided above. Thank You :)

Comment: @DanMašek Also, How can I extract an image if the points are more than 4 and it's an irregular polygon?

Comment: That's why I was asking for you to elaborate a bit, perhaps make some illustrations of some possible scenarios (of how the points are laid out), and how you expect the resulting "extracted image" to look like. For example, if they define a rectangle with horizontal/vertical edges, then it's quite obvious. But, let's say, the points define a square that's rotated 45 degrees, (like ◇) -- what do you want to get as a result? Just the smallest image that fits it all? Parts outside the square blacked out? Rotate the image first, so the edges are parallel and then crop tightly? Same with 5+ points.

Comment: @DanMašek I got it to work. I've shred the code. PLease can you tell me how to extract only the masked region? Thank You. I don't want the entire image.

Comment: You can get the bounding rectangle for the region: `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(arr_points)` and then use that to select the ROI: `result = out[y:y+h,x:x+w]`

Comment: @DanMašek What if the shape is not rectangular and is irregular? I cannot use boundingRect right? What can I use instead? Thank You, Dan.

Comment: You can, it will just find the smallest rectangle into which the shape will fit, and you will have some black parts left there. Since images are rectangular, there really isn't a way around that (at most you could perhaps make the masked out areas transparent if that's what you desire).